# Convert beam pro API on GitHub to jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, api, maven, jar

I tried using the [beam API](https://dev.beam.pro) in Java, but to use it inside of Eclipse, i need a JAR-File of the API. I wasn't able to convert the API on GitHub into a JAR.

And yes i tried converting it using Maven ...

Can anyone convert the API to a JAR file for me, or is there another way to convert it? Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/WatchBeam/beam-client-java

Comment: What have you tried? (specifically, paste commands or steps)  What was the result? (paste error messages or outcome)

Comment: Tried installing maven on mac to make a JAR out of it. After following all the installation steps in terminal, it still wasn't installed.

Comment: What wasn't installed? What do you mean by installed? How are you building your own project?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the jar file yourself from the github repo, then you need to clone the repo, run the maven build, and copy the jar out of the `target` directory.

```
git clone https://github.com/WatchBeam/beam-client-java.git
cd beam-client-java
mvn clean install
cp target/api-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar /path/to/some/dir
```

If you're content with just downloading the jar, you can find it in beam's maven repository here: https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/snapshots/pro/beam/api/

Comment: The first 2 lines you gave did work, but if i paste in the third and run it, it says: "-bash: mvn: command not found"

Comment: Sorry im not used to this, iv'e used simple pre-build jars until now :S

Comment: How did you install maven on your mac? If you have maven installed correctly, the `mvn` command will be found.

Comment: Also, if you're happy with the pre-built jar, you can use my second suggestion and not worry about using maven.